# Computing total rank for multiple columns using NSE syntax

Tags: r, dplyr, nse, tidyeval

My goal is to write a function `take_by_rank` that

- can operate on arbitrary selection of numeric columns within a data frame;
- uses non-standard evaluation like `base::subset` or `dplyr` verbs;
- understands the minus sign naturally, so that `-foo` means "the largest value of `foo` gets the lowest rank";
- returns `n` top or bottom rows by the total rank, which is the sum of ranks computed for each of the selected variables.

I'm interested in both learning the newest [dplyr way](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) and looking for alternative approaches, i.e. there is no restriction on package selection (pure `base` or `data.table` maybe?).

**My current solution is**

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

take_by_rank <- function(df, ..., n = 100) {
    selected_vars <- quos(...)
    if (!length(selected_vars))
        stop("No variables to rank!")
    prefix <- ".rank_"
    for (i in seq_along(selected_vars)) {
        rank_name <- paste0(prefix, quo_name(selected_vars[[i]]))
        df <- df %>%
            mutate(!!rank_name := frankv(!!selected_vars[[i]]))
    }
    df %>%
        mutate(TotalRank = rowSums(select(df, starts_with(prefix)))) %>%
        arrange(TotalRank) %>%
        top_n(n, -TotalRank)
}
```

It seems to be okay, but maybe I'm missing something more straightforward. If there's a way to replace the for loop, that would also be nice.

**Usage examples** (for reference)

```
take_by_rank(mtcars, mpg, qsec, n = 3)
   mpg cyl disp  hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear carb .rank_mpg .rank_qsec TotalRank
1 13.3   8  350 245 3.73 3.84 15.41  0  0    3    4         3          3         6
2 15.0   8  301 335 3.54 3.57 14.60  0  1    5    8         6          2         8
3 14.3   8  360 245 3.21 3.57 15.84  0  0    3    4         4          5         9

take_by_rank(mtcars, mpg, qsec, n = -3)
   mpg cyl  disp hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb .rank_mpg .rank_qsec TotalRank
1 22.8   4 140.8 95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2      24.5         32      56.5
2 32.4   4  78.7 66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1      31.0         27      58.0
3 33.9   4  71.1 65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1      32.0         28      60.0

take_by_rank(mtcars, mpg, -qsec, n = 3)
   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb .rank_mpg .rank_-qsec TotalRank
1 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1      14.0           2      16.0
2 10.4   8  472 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4       1.5          15      16.5
3 10.4   8  460 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4       1.5          16      17.5
```

Comment: maybe you could replace the for loop with dplyr::mutate_at()

Comment: `mutate_at` does have a lot of potential here to replace the loop if you are willing to switch to adding `rank` as a suffix on the new columns instead of the prefix.

Comment: @aosmith @AlexP I thought so as well, but `mutate_at` does not treat `-foo` correclty (example 3 and my comment below), so I cannot use it without manual intervention that strips out the minus sign.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the dots to `vars()` before passing them to `mutate_at()`

```
mutate_at(df, vars(...), myfuns)
```

This is equivalent to passing the dots to `tidyselect::vars_select()` and then to `mutate_at()`:

```
vars <- tidyselect::vars_select(tbl_vars(df), ...)
mutate_at(df, vars, myfuns)
```

Comment: Good to know, thanks. However the `-qsec` semantics will have different meaning then (see my other comments).

Answer (score 1):

As Alex P also suggest you can use `mutate_at()` to remove the for loop, we can then rewrite the function as:

```
take_by_rank <- function(df, ..., n = 100) {
  selected_vars <- quos(...)
  if (!length(selected_vars))
    stop("No variables to rank!")
  df <- df %>% 
    mutate_at(selected_vars,  funs(rank = frankv)) %>%  
    mutate(TotalRank = rowSums(select(., ends_with("_rank")))) %>%
    arrange(TotalRank) %>%
    top_n(n, -TotalRank)
}
```

This will apply `frankv` to all selected vars and add new columns with the suffix _rank. I also  changed the select statement to reference the piped data.frame. If you want to have complete variable name matching for the Totalrank calculation this will work.

```
 take_by_rank_matching <- function(df, ..., n = 100) {
      selected_vars <- quos(...)
      if (!length(selected_vars))
        stop("No variables to rank!")
      df <- df %>% 
        mutate_at(selected_vars,  funs(rank = frankv)) %>%  
        mutate(TotalRank = rowSums(
          select_at(., unlist(lapply(selected_vars,
                                     function(x)
                                       paste0(quo_label(x), "_rank")))))) %>%
        arrange(TotalRank) %>%
        top_n(n, -TotalRank)
    }
```

Although I think there might be a cleaner way.

Comment: I like the `mutate_at` idea, but this breaks the `-qsec` example.

Answer (score 0):

As you noted the use of `mutate_at` make it impossible (or very hard) to work with the `-foo` behavior.

I propose you this solution. It's not extremely different from what you did.
I changed the `for-loop` with `purrr::map`, and streamlined the creation of `total_rank`.

```
library(tidyverse)
# ....
library(rlang)
# ....

take_by_rank <- function(df, ..., n = 100) {
    # original quosures
    selected_vars <- quos(...)

    if (!length(selected_vars))
        stop("No variables to rank!")

    suffixed_vars <- map(selected_vars, ~ {
        paste0(quo_name(.x), '_rank') %>%
            as.name() %>%
            as_quosure()
    })

    selected_vars %>%
        map( ~ {
            rank_name <- paste0(quo_name(.x), '_rank')
            df %>%                   # or whatever rank function you want
                mutate(!!rank_name := dense_rank(!!.x))
        }) %>%
        reduce(full_join) %>%
        mutate(total_rank = '+'(!!!suffixed_vars)) %>% # !!! = unquote and splice
        top_n(n, -total_rank)

}

take_by_rank(mtcars, mpg, qsec, n = 3)
#> Joining, by = c("mpg", "cyl", "disp", "hp", "drat", "wt", "qsec", "vs", "am", "gear", "carb")
#>    mpg cyl disp  hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear carb mpg_rank qsec_rank
#> 1 14.3   8  360 245 3.21 3.57 15.84  0  0    3    4        3         5
#> 2 13.3   8  350 245 3.73 3.84 15.41  0  0    3    4        2         3
#> 3 15.0   8  301 335 3.54 3.57 14.60  0  1    5    8        5         2
#>   total_rank
#> 1          8
#> 2          5
#> 3          7

take_by_rank(mtcars, mpg, qsec, n = -3)
#> Joining, by = c("mpg", "cyl", "disp", "hp", "drat", "wt", "qsec", "vs", "am", "gear", "carb")
#>    mpg cyl  disp hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb mpg_rank qsec_rank
#> 1 22.8   4 140.8 95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2       19        30
#> 2 32.4   4  78.7 66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1       24        25
#> 3 33.9   4  71.1 65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1       25        26
#>   total_rank
#> 1         49
#> 2         49
#> 3         51

take_by_rank(mtcars, mpg, -qsec, n = 3)
#> Joining, by = c("mpg", "cyl", "disp", "hp", "drat", "wt", "qsec", "vs", "am", "gear", "carb")
#>    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb mpg_rank -qsec_rank
#> 1 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1       12          2
#> 2 10.4   8  472 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4        1         14
#> 3 10.4   8  460 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4        1         15
#>   total_rank
#> 1         14
#> 2         15
#> 3         16

take_by_rank(mtcars, mpg,  n = 3)
#>    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb mpg_rank total_rank
#> 1 10.4   8  472 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4        1          1
#> 2 10.4   8  460 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4        1          1
#> 3 13.3   8  350 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4        2          2
```